# dotnet pack for .NET Core project produces .nupkg file with sources

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget

I have a simple .NET Core 2.1 class library project and need to pack it as a Nuget package. For that I'm using this command:

```
dotnet pack <project>.csproj --output <outputFolder> /p:Configuration=Release
```

But, I'm getting this warning:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.502\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\build\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(202,5): warning NU5100: The assembly 'obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\<assembly>.dll' is not inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
```

I understand that `lib` folders are for targeting multiple frameworks, but I don't want that. I only want to target .NET Core 2.1.

At the end my `.nupkg` file is created, but it has all the source code (don't know why) and when used in other projects, they cannot reference the assemblies, because they are inside the `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1` folder.

I've seen some guides to create Nuget packages from .Net Core projects and none of them mention something related to `lib` folders.

I need to understand if something is missing or if I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

**Edit: Added the project file and the .nuspec file**

Project File:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <Company>xxx</Company>
    <RootNamespace>xxxx</RootNamespace>
    <Product>xxxx</Product>
    <Authors>xxxx</Authors>
    <NuspecFile>xxxxx.nuspec</NuspecFile>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="5.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`.nuspec` File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>xxxxxx</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>xxxx</title>
    <owners>xxxx</owners>
    <description>xxxx</description>
    <authors>xxxx.</authors>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019 xxxx.</copyright>
    <summary>xxx is a common code library for internal projects.</summary>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Comment: Can you give us your `.csproj`? This one's going to be nice and juicy.

Comment: Added `.csproj` file.

Comment: Could you explain why you have a nuspec file at all? I think you should be able to specify everything in just the .csproj file. I haven't used a nuspec file for a long time.

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that `.nuspec` files are not needed anymore, so I like the idea to have the package properties in a separate file. But that was causing the issue. Once I removed the `.nuspec` file, it started to create package as expected!

Answer (score 1):

There appear to be a few misunderstandings here.

Firstly, the `lib` folder in the `nupkg` is not for multitargetting, but for all dlls that are part of the build. If your package only supports 1 target framework moniker (TFM), then your `nupkg` will only have a single folder under `lib`, for example `lib/netstandard2.0/MyLib.dll`, or possibly `lib/netcoreapp2.1/MyLib.dll` if your app uses APIs that are part of the .NET Core 2.1 runtime, but not netstandard. If your project only uses APIs that are part of netstandard, there's no benefit to targetting netcoreapp and has potential problems which might cause you issues in the future, even if it works fine today.

Secondly, a simple class library (to me this means the project only contains `.cs` files and no content files, no build file, the package will only contain the dll and NuGet's own files) shouldn't need to know anything about what's inside a `nupkg`. Even more complex projects that multitarget don't need to care about the `lib` folder when using an SDK style project. Just specify your target TFMs in the `<TargetFrameworks>` element, and let the SDK pack the `nupkg` itself. It knows what to do. If you've done anything in your `csproj` to try to force the output dll to a different location within the `nupkg`, it's more likely to cause problem than improve things.

Without seeing your `.csproj`, I cant' guess what you could have done to get that warning message on pack, but like I said, a brand new `dotnet new classlib` packs just fine, and if your project only contains code files, you shouldn't need anything in the `csproj` related to pack paths.

Comment: Yes, I'm not trying to do anything out of the standard. It's just a class library with `.cs` files that I want to pack in a nuget package. But since the first time I tried to do that, I got the described result. I'm adding the project file in the original question, and the `.nuspec file`. Thanks

Comment: @GustavoVargas you don't need a nuspec file with SDK style projects. Delete it and let the SDK generate it for you. [The metadata you want in the nuspec can be specified in the csproj using MSBuild properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target).

Comment: The documentation doesn't say that `.nuspec` files are not needed anymore, so I like the idea to have the package properties in a separate file. But that was causing the issue. Once I removed the `.nuspec` file, it started to create package as expected! Please modify your answer to add that, and I'll mark it as answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: The nuget docs were mostly written before .NET Core existed and we no longer have a team dedicated to updating the docs (I work for the NuGet team at Microsoft, and yes, at some point before I joined the team there were people dedicated to docs). If there's a specific page you used to come to the conclusion to use a nuspec file with a SDK project, please let me know which one and I may update it. But we have higher priority work, so it's hard to find time to make major updates to the docs to make it clear the difference between SDK projects and "old style" projects.

Comment: I understand that.
I think the main problem here is the unexpected behavior when I used the `.nuspec` file.
I read again the documentation, and although[This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) says that for .NET Core, Nuget uses information from the csproj file directly, it doesn't say that `.nuspec` files are not allowed, or not recommended, so if it still allows the use of `.nuspec` file then it should behave correctly, if not, then it's better to at least give a warning or error related to that.That's my feedback.
Thanks again for your time!